# Color (CMYK) leakage when using precompiled format file?

Tags: color, format-files

EDIT3: Note - the below apparently demonstrates a bug with Ghostscript 9.02's `tiffsep` device (see comments); tested it with Ghostscript 9.16 and it doesn't display this problem (CMYK separations are OK, black plate only, in both cases). But see also the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243625/2595), which fixes this with also with `gs` 9.02. Still, caveat emptor...

---

Consider this MWE, `test.tex` (this is on Texlive 2014, updated to frozen):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\pdfcompresslevel=0 % edit: added

\usepackage[fixpdftex,cmyk,svgnames]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\typecmyk#1{%
\typeout{XC@mod@cmyk #1: \XC@mod@cmyk} % is 'cmyk' when active
} \typecmyk{A}
\makeatother

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=15cm,
  paperheight=20cm,
  outer=2cm,
  inner=2cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}
\crop[cam,info] % info is default, noinfo has to be set; use [off] to turn off all marks

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty} %disable headers and footers
\pagenumbering{roman} %use roman page numbering in the frontmatter

\section{Another one}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

If we compile this as usual, and rename the output as `test1.pdf`:

```bash
pdflatex test.tex
mv test.pdf test1.pdf
```

... then we can output the CMYK separations using `ghostscript`:

```bash
gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffsep -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r72x72 \
 -sOutputFile=test1.tif -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 test1.pdf
montage \
 test1.Cyan.tif test1.Magenta.tif test1.Yellow.tif test1.Black.tif \
 -border 1 -bordercolor lime -geometry +2+2 -tile x1 \
 test1_cmyk.png
```

... and with ImageMagick's `montage` we can put all CMYK separations on one image, and the result is this (click for high-res):

[image: test1_cmyk.png]

The text is supposed to be black - and indeed, there is "ink" only on the K plate, as expected. So all is good in this case.

But now, let's try compile the same example with "precompiled" format files; and retrieve the separations:

```bash
pdflatex -ini -jobname="test" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "test.tex" 
pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 "&test" test.tex
mv test.pdf test2.pdf
gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffsep -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r72x72 \
 -sOutputFile=test2.tif -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 test2.pdf
montage \
 test2.Cyan.tif test2.Magenta.tif test2.Yellow.tif test2.Black.tif \
 -border 1 -bordercolor lime -geometry +2+2 -tile x1 \
 test2_cmyk.png
```

... but now, the separations are like this:

[image: test2_cmyk.png]

... and it is as if for the text color only, the color black is as if defined in RGB - and then transformed to CMYK in the plainest/"dumbest" form possible: with color on *all* plates (instead of only on the black one), which is going to cost me a lot more in the print shop.

<s>The weird thing is - we can uncompress the resulting PDFs with `pdftk`</s> EDIT: now with `\pdfcompresslevel=0` there is no need to uncompress with `pdftk`, we can observe test1.pdf/test2.pdf directly as they are uncompressed.... EDIT2: now these files have been uploaded here:

- [test1.pdf](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/cmyk/test1.pdf)
- [test2.pdf](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/tex/cmyk/test2.pdf)

... and while these unfortunately cannot be compared with `meld`, with `less -L test1.pdf` they can be inspected, and for the text part, the PDF output is somewhat different:

```
% test1.pdf
Q
0 g 0 G
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
0 g 0 G
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
BT
/F16 14.3462 Tf 141.732 637.754 Td [(0.1)-1125(Another)-375(one)]TJ/F8 9.9626 Tf
 0 -21.821 Td [(Lorem)-315(ipsum)-315(dolor)-316(sit)-315(amet,)-319(consectetur
)-315(adipiscing)-315(elit,)-319(sed)-315(do)-315(eiusmo)-28(d)]TJ 0 -11.955 Td 
...
rum.)]TJ
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
ET

% test2.pdf
Q
0 g 0 G
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
0 g 0 G
BT
/F28 14.3462 Tf 141.732 637.754 Td [(0.1)-1125(Another)-375(one)]TJ/F8 9.9626 Tf
 0 -21.821 Td [(Lorem)-315(ipsum)-315(dolor)-316(sit)-315(amet,)-319(consectetur
)-315(adipiscing)-315(elit,)-319(sed)-315(do)-315(eiusmo)-28(d)]TJ 0 -11.955 Td 
...
rum.)]TJ
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
0 g 0 G
ET
```

... but the weird thing is, CMYK color model seems to be used always (`k` or `K`) and there is no sign of RGB (i.e. `rg` and `RG`) - so I am completely puzzled on as to where this leakage of black to the other components comes from ?!

So my question is - why does this "color leakage" happen when using a precompiled format file; and how can I get the correct result also with a precompiled format file?

EDIT: Shameless plug: I discovered this thanks to my patch to `pdfshuffler` for showing CMYK separations, given in [Linux GUI for quick browsing of CMYK separations of multi-page PDF? - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19210/linux-gui-for-quick-browsing-of-cmyk-separations-of-multi-page-pdf/19321#19321)

Comment: Maybe the `pdftk` does some color corrections. Try to do your color separations after `pdftk` or try to set `\pdfcompresslevel=0` in order to avoid the usage of `pdftk`.

Comment: Thanks @wipet - the `pdftk` is in there just to show how I get to the uncompressed PDF literals; otherwise the color separations in the post above are all derived via `pdflatex` -> `ghostscript` (-> `montage`) directly. `\pdfcompresslevel=0` is a good idea, though, then `pdftk` would indeed not be needed. Cheers!

Comment: Hi again @wipet - I may have misunderstood you at first, if you were referring to "color corrections" being done specifically for the snippet in the post with PDF literal code. So I repeated the whole process with `\pdfcompresslevel=0` and updated the post with the results - but it seems the conclusion (there is a slight difference, but only `k`, `K` are used) remains the same. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: My idea was that the compressed PDF hides something like `1 1 1 1 k` and `pdftk` does correction of this and prints `0 0 0 1 k`. The parts of your `PDF` shows `0 0 0 1 k` and this is impossible to separate this to the result you shown. I tried to experiment with `0 0 0 1 k` settings and with the separation using `gs` (similar as you) and I have normal result: black part is only at the last plate.

Comment: what happens if you put `\normalcolor` after `\begin{document}` ?

Comment: Thnaks @wipet - I see; I included those parts of the PDF just to emphasize the problem wasn't trivial `:)` I know attached links to the actual `test1` and `test2` PDFs (see OP edit), so the full PDF files can be checked out now; @DavidCarlisle - just tried `\normalcolor` after `\begin{document}` - no change (still leaking when using precompiled header)

Comment: I started with your two PDFs test1 and test2 and I applied your separation process using gs. Of course, I was very care to distinguish between test1 and test2 (many occurrences on command lines), but the result is the same in both cases: CMY are empty and K includes typesetting. It means that all is right. I cannot reproduce problem.

Comment: Thanks for the report, @wipet - so that may be a bug in ghostscript; my `gs --version` is 9.02; it's possible there may have been a bug with the `tiffsep` device in this version, fixed since then. Cheers!

Comment: Just tested with ghostscript 9.16 - and indeed, it does not display this bug; edited OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases, `0 g 0 G` can be seen in the PDF files. This comes from
the PDF color stack of pdfTeX that is not yet reassigned to CMYK values.
This can be done by:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\InitColorStack}{%
  \chardef\main@pdfcolorstack=\pdfcolorstackinit{0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K}\relax
}
\InitColorStack
\everyjob\expandafter{\the\everyjob\InitColorStack}
\makeatother
```

The status of pdfTeX's color stacks are *not* saved in the format file, therefore they need to be set also with the own format file. This is done by the setting of the token register `\everyjob`.

Now, the color settings `0 g 0 G` in the gray model are gone in both PDF files and the separation should be more successful.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @HeikoOberdiek: I added your snippet right after the `\pdfcompresslevel=0` in the preamble in the OP - and now even when I compile with precompiled header, the separations are OK -- and even with ghostscript 9.02! Great with a fix for this - cheers!